# How to add an Azure App Service extension via powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service

Our continuous integration environment automatically deploys a new Azure App Service on each deploy. So this means it removes the old staging slot and re-creates it again before swapping into production. So we get a fresh start and all new configuration and services are deployed.

This has been fine until now we also need a useful site extension installed. When we install this extension manually it will just get lost when we do a fresh deploy again.

How can I install a site extension to an Azure App Service via powershell? My CI process can do this easily.

Comment: This needs more detail, e.g: what CI system are you using, what extension needs installing, what code have you tried already?

Comment: -1 for tagging `Powershell` but there's no error producing code or any powershell at all. Please edit your question and include the details that @MarkWragg suggested.

Comment: Do you check this [link](http://poshdb.com/home/install-azure-app-extension-powershell/)?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for. How can I mark that as the answer? Can you just add it please and ill mark it complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check this [example](http://poshdb.com/home/install-azure-app-extension-powershell/).

```
### Install NewRelic Extension for Azure App###
write-output "*** Installing New Relic on PROD Site"
$WebSite = "your site name"
$Kudu = "https://" + $WebSite + ".scm.azurewebsites.net/api/extensionfeed" # Here you can get a list for all Extensions available.
$InstallNRURI = "https://" + $WebSite + ".scm.azurewebsites.net/api/siteextensions" # Install API EndPoint

$username = "`$UserName"
$password = "hxWN9sjrqt9haA3NpG1kTK0QBui2ph7cEGQlcMQhYTiWqDWL9yf1aXGIJHTD"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$invoke = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Kudu -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method get ###-InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"

$id = ($invoke | ? {$_.id -match "NewRelic*"}).id  ### Searching for NewRelic ID Extension

try {
    $InstallNewRelic = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$InstallNRURI/$id" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Put
    $Status = ($InstallNewRelic.provisioningState).ToString() + "|" + ($InstallNewRelic.installed_date_time).ToString()  ### Status
    Write-Output "NewRelic Installation Status : $Status"
    Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $WebSite -Verbose ### Restarting the WebApp
}
catch{$_}
```

Comment: This would be using the Kudu API to manage site extensions via PowerShell. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API

I didn't know what I was looking for until Walter found a solution.

Comment: @Walter - is it possible to authenticate using VSTS's OAuth token?

Comment: The OAuth token cannot be used for authentication.